# Using "the" with this mode of transportation

Tags: articles, definite-article

If I want to refer to [the Mass Rapid Transit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_Rapid_Transit) as a means of transportation that I used to get to a zoo in the city, do I need to use the article "the" then?

In short, should it be:

> 1) I took MRT to get to the zoo.

or

> 2) I took **the** MRT to get to the zoo.

?

Answer (score 1):

Each are possible, but I favour use of the article (ie: “the MRT”).

For example, Lonely Planet (when speaking of Singapore) says:

> In the inner city, the MRT runs underground...

While an Australian news outlet (when speaking of Jakarta) says:

> ...that the MRT itself could not resolve Jakarta's traffic jams...

There is no firm “rule” here for an article before an initialism and all of these may play a part:

- context
- variety of English
- popular usage in a particular city
- formality of setting

Comment: In all your examples MRT is the subject of a sentence, but what if I use it as a direct object like in my example - especially when I simply describe the way how I got to some place: 'I took MRT', 'I went there by MRT', 'It'll take you only 10 minutes by MRT', etc - will using 'the' not be odd then?

Comment: I do take your point. I can find the use of “take MRT” in Singaporean English in particular when I do a google search, but it appears infrequent compared with “take the MRT”. For example, google ngram has no data for “take MRT” whereas “take the MRT” registers.  In the end all I can say is that, in my Australian English idiolect, “take MRT” sounds unnatural, whether MRT is a subject or direct object.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, [***initialism** don't take articles.](https://ontariotraining.net/grammar-tip-the-with-acronyms-and-initialisms/)

So, it'd be like -

> I took ***MRT*** to get to the zoo.

If you find an article in such cases, the initialism probably serves as an adjective.

> I talked to ***an MRT*** motorman.

Comment: But according to the source you've provided MRT is not an acronym, but an initialism.

Comment: Ah, true! Corrected. MRT is initialism and won't have the article. @brilliant

Comment: (1) I am still a bit confused. The source cited by you says, “**Use a definite article with an initialism if the spelled out term begins with “the” but is not covered in the initialism**” and gives an example: “**the United States of America = the U.S.A.**” And later it says, “**When “the” is not part of the full name, then it is not inserted before the initialism.**”

Comment: (2) Now, the question is how do I determine if “the” is part of the full name or not? I thought that the titles of Wikipedia articles would do that, but neither the wiki article about the Mass Rapid Transit (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_Rapid_Transit), nor the article about the United States of America ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States ) contain “the” in the title. If so, then, following the rule given in your source, I will have to drop “the” before MRT,  but then I would also have to drop "the" before "USA", yet your source says that I should keep it: "the USA".

Comment: It's about whether ***the*** is legally registered as a name. The *article* 'the', in many cases, are registered with the name; say - ***The*** Coca Cola Company. For the sake of brevity, MRT is used IMO. @brilliant

Comment: But where do I find out how a certain entity is legally registered?

Comment: They are mostly **names**